# How to sort all items according to registration date in dynamoose

Tags: node.js, sorting, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

Summary:
How to sort all items according to registration date. When I tried it gives me no output, My code is shown below

Code sample:

```
abcdschema.statics.fetchall = function fetchall(cb) {
    var id_temp='abcd';
    this.query('id').contains(id_temp).where('regDate').ascending(function(err,res){
        console.log(err,res);
    })
}
```

Schema

```
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    hashKey: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    rangeKey: true
},
regDate: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
activeFlag: { type: Boolean, default: true }
```

Environment:

- Operating System: ubuntu
- Operating System Version:14.04
- Node.js version (node -v):9.3.0
- NPM version: (npm -v):5.5.1
- Dynamoose version:0.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Few issues here.

1. You have to use [`Query.exec()`](https://dynamoosejs.com/api/query/#queryexeccallback) to pass in your callback function instead of passing it into the ascending function.
2. You must use [`Query.eq()`](https://dynamoosejs.com/api/query#queryeqvalue) for your hash key.
3. You must use the `index` property on your schema, and use the `rangeKey` property to sort using that. See [this line](https://github.com/dynamoosejs/dynamoose/blob/5be0d182e3a6ead82bda7c471ce4c431f24209d7/test/Query.js#L47) and [this line](https://github.com/dynamoosejs/dynamoose/blob/5be0d182e3a6ead82bda7c471ce4c431f24209d7/test/Query.js#L270) in the tests for more details on how to do a descending query.